# conversion ActiveX to NPAPI

Tags: activex, npapi

How can I convert ActiveX app to NPAPI app?

All I found a way is implementing Entry Points and mapping functions for NPAPI. (NPP_GetEntryPoints...)
Is this only way except for re-writing app using Framework?

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write a layer that translates between NPAPI and the ActiveX control (for both directions). While it should be possible to solve this mostly generically, i'm not aware of any drop-in-code you could just use.

If you consider using [FireBreath](http://firebreath.org), this [ActiveX wrapper example](https://github.com/firebreath/FBAXExample) should help you. Note that if you can afford to port your plugin to FireBreath, it already generates NPAPI and ActiveX plugins from one source base for you.